# protobuf generated files does not compile on Solaris SPARC 64

Tags: compiler-construction, 64-bit, solaris, protocol-buffers

I am trying to compile some generated proto.cc files on Solaris 10 SPARC 64.

And I get these errors:

```
"/apps/pkgs/studio-11.0.13/prod/include/CC/stlport4/stl/_alloc.h", line 134: Error: The function "__stl_new" must have a prototype.
"/apps/pkgs/studio-11.0.13/prod/include/CC/stlport4/stl/_alloc.h", line 135: Error: The function "__stl_delete" must have a prototype.
"/apps/pkgs/studio-11.0.13/prod/include/CC/stlport4/./stdexcept", line 52: Error: _STLP_EXCEPTION_BASE is not defined.
```

Compiler flags are:

```
/apps/pkgs/studio-11.0.13/prod/bin/CC -xarch=v9 -library=stlport4 -library=Crun -features=no%conststrings -library=no%rwtools7 -erroff=nonewline
```

protobuf compiler flags:

```
CXXFLAGS = -xmemalign=8s -g0 -xO3 -xlibmil -xdepend -xbuiltin -mt -compat=5 -library=stlport4 -library=Crun -template=no%extdef  -DNDEBUG -m64 -xarch=v9
```

protobuf was compiled successfully(all tests passed)

Thanks,
Bogdan

Comment: You might get some help here on SO, however; my understanding is that the core google maintainers aren't SO users. You may find the [google group](http://groups.google.com/group/protobuf) helpful in this instance.

Comment: Seems that stlport used on Solaris is too old, even for studio-11.0.13. Is there an stlport5?

Comment: No, I tried also with studio-12.0.1 and it has only stlport4

Comment: ok, but why the protobuf tests passed using stlport4 ? The problem is not stlport4. It might be a conflict with native stl but I don't know how to avoid it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so it seams that our code is build with native stl, which means we cannot link it with protobuf build with stlport4. So I had to build protobuf with native stl.

Here are the steps:

```
1. You have to apply these patches: https://gar.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/gar/csw/mgar/pkg/protobuf/trunk/files/

2.Run ./configure with these parameters:

./configure LDFLAGS=-L$PWD/src/solaris --disable-64bit-solaris --prefix=/bogdan/protobuf-2.4.1

If you want to build it on SPARC 64, remove --disable-64bit-solaris and edit protobuf-2.4.1/src/solaris/libstdc++.la file to add the correct dependecies to the linker.

3. Run: make, make check and make install
```

Regards,
Bogdan

Comment: From what I can tell, these patches are for 2.3.0 not for 2.4.1 and don't apply cleanly. Did you have to fix up the hunks that fail by hand?