# Protobuf-2.6.1 compile error on Solaris 10 SPARC 64

Tags: c++, gcc, solaris-10, protobuf-c, pointer-conversion

When trying to compile Protobuf-2.6.1 on Solaris 10 SPARC 64, I get:

```
./google/protobuf/stubs/once.h: In function `void google::protobuf::GoogleOnceInit(google::protobuf::ProtobufOnceType*, void (*)())':
./google/protobuf/stubs/once.h:125: error: cannot convert `google::protobuf::ProtobufOnceType*' to `const volatile google::protobuf::internal::Atomic32*' for argument `1' to `google::protobuf::internal::Atomic32 google::protobuf::internal::Acquire_Load(const volatile google::protobuf::internal::Atomic32*)'
./google/protobuf/stubs/once.h: In function `void google::protobuf::GoogleOnceInit(google::protobuf::ProtobufOnceType*, void (*)(Arg*), Arg*)':
./google/protobuf/stubs/once.h:134: error: cannot convert `google::protobuf::ProtobufOnceType*' to `const volatile google::protobuf::internal::Atomic32*' for argument `1' to `google::protobuf::internal::Atomic32 google::protobuf::internal::Acquire_Load(const volatile google::protobuf::internal::Atomic32*)'
```

I followed the Official README, `./configure` and `make`.

The compiler version(GCC):

```
$ gcc -v
Reading specs from /usr/sfw/lib/gcc/sparc-sun-solaris2.10/3.4.3/specs
Configured with: /sfw10/builds/build/sfw10-patch/usr/src/cmd/gcc/gcc-3.4.3/configure --prefix=/usr/sfw --with-as=/usr/ccs/bin/as --without-gnu-as --with-ld=/usr/ccs/bin/ld --without-gnu-ld --enable-languages=c,c++ --enable-shared
Thread model: posix
gcc version 3.4.3 (csl-sol210-3_4-branch+sol_rpath)
```

I also read the question [protobuf generated files does not compile on Solaris SPARC 64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8167424/protobuf-generated-files-does-not-compile-on-solaris-sparc-64) and tried, but it didn't work. That article works on Protobuf-2.4.1, but Protobuf-2.6.1 changes:

```
2014-10-20 version 2.6.1:

  C++
  * Added atomicops support for Solaris.
```

Is there any way to make GCC do force pointer conversion?

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem according to the github issue [#789](https://github.com/google/protobuf/pull/789)

The main reason is methioned in the 4th point of this issue. The predefined SOLARIS_64BIT_ENABLED macro takes no effect at all.

The problem can be solved simply by adding `-m64 -DSOLARIS_64BIT_ENABLED` to CXXFLAGS and CFLAGS. But it's better to do whole modification as the issue suggested.